# Getting below error in browser when executing an onclick function in ionic-4 project

Tags: ionic4

I am working on ionic-4 project but some jquery function suddenly stopped working and I am getting an error in browser's console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using jQuery normally in an Angular / Ionic project. It's a different way of thinking about things.

Are you saying that it somehow worked and then stopped working, or you have tried to merge some jQuery code into an Ionic 4 project and it's not ever worked?

Please update your question to show the `addinput` code, and as much code as you have that will allow people to answer your question.

It could be that you have made it `private` - is that listed before the method declaration?

Or it could be that you've just dropped some completely random code into your project that's not compatible.